# Where is it correct to store a constant in Vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

It's simple, I have a very long api url 'https://namerandomlarge.api.com/'.

I would like to store it in a variable called **MyApiUrl**, so I can use it in my components and methods whenever I want.

What would be the right way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

I usually put things like that in a constants.js file in project folder.

```
export const API_BASE = "http://localhost:5000/api"
```

or as a .env variable if it is something I wouldn't want in git repo.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `.env` file and access it through your application.

```
API_URL=https://namerandomlarge.api.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `.env` file in your root directory of the project and then add the common URL's in that file.

```
MY_API_URL=https://namerandomlarge.api.com/
```

You can access this in your component script code like this **:**

```
process.env.MY_API_URL
```

One advantage of creating `.env` file is that you can use these files dynamically based on the environment. For example : In Dev, you want to execute some different URL's and in prod env, You have some different. In this case you can create two env files `.env.dev` and `.env.prod` and then call based on the environments you are running.

Comment: I feel like this answer does not fully represent the usage of env variables. How to set up and use environment variables can differ according to the setup. For example, using vite, you can access env variables as [`import.meta.env`](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-files).