# Best practice to to set non-reactive const variables in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scope, constants

**The situation**

In my Vue app, I have a Vue component which mounts an svg, which I have defined with a few props. These are a combination of reactive and non-reactive data.
The reactive data that we need is `percData`, which therefore sits in the `data(){}` object.
We also have `colours`, `width`, `height`, and `scale`, which are not reactive and never will be. I don't call these in the `<template>` block, and I don't plan for them to change. These are currently declared with `const`, and are not within the `export defautl{}` block scope.

**The question(s)**

- Where is the best place to be for these const declarations?
- What scope are these const-declared variables currently in?
- More generally, how does scope work for the `<script>` tag in Vue in a multi-component app? Is each script/component a separate scope from the global one? And where is the global scope?

**My possible understanding**

As per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72693744/where-is-it-correct-to-store-a-constant-in-vue3) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47597384/canonical-way-to-define-common-constants-in-vue-js), I think the best place for my const would be in a separate file, from which I would then import them in my `mySvgComponent` component. Is this the correct approach?

**My code**

```
<template>
    <div></div>
</template>

<script>
    import { mySvgComponent} from '../mySvgComponent'
    import { select } from 'd3'

    const [colour1, colour2, colour3, colour4] = ['#000000', '#111111', '#222222', '#3333'];
    
    const width = 135
    const height = 135
    const scale = .75

    export default {
        name:'mySvgComponent', 
        data(){ 
            return{
                percData: null
            }
        },
        props: {
            summary: Object
        },
        methods: {
            percSetup(summary) {
                return this.percData = [
                    { colour: colour1, perc: +summary.colour1Percentage.toFixed(2)},
                    { colour: colour2, perc: +summary.colour2Percentage.toFixed(2)},
                    { colour: colour3, perc: +summary.colour3Percentage.toFixed(2)},
                    { colour: colour4, perc: +summary.colour4Percentage.toFixed(2)}
                ]
            }
        },
        async mounted() {
            this.percSetup(this.$props.summary)
          
            const svg = 
                select('div')
                .append('svg')
                .call(mySvgComponent(this.percData)
                .width(width)
                .height(height)
                .scale(scale))
        }
    }
</script>
<style></style>
```

**Related threads and why I don't think they answer my question:**

1. [How to set a component non-reactive data in Vue 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45814507/how-to-set-a-component-non-reactive-data-in-vue-2), [How to make a template variable non-reactive in Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52843873/how-to-make-a-template-variable-non-reactive-in-vue), [How could I use const in vue template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42662144/how-could-i-use-const-in-vue-template). I don't call my const variables in my `<template>` tag, and I don't need it to be responsive.
2. [What is the best way to create a constant, that can be accessible from entire application in VueJs ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46882944/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-constant-that-can-be-accessible-from-entire-ap). Maybe I don't understand this fully. Why would I need to run a `method()` to return my const variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue SFC is syntax sugar, it's necessary to understand what code it's compiled to in order to use it effectively.

The result of SFC `script` syntax is ES module with roughly the same content as the body of `<script>` block, with `name` and `render` options being added by the compiler. Then general modular JavaScript practices are applicable. The constants can remain in current module if they don't take much lines and aren't reused in other modules, and can be moved to a separate module otherwise. In case the constants are supposed to be used in a template, they can be returned from `data` or `setup` function.

The result of SFC `script setup` syntax is ES module with the whole block being moved to generated `setup` function, with the exception of imports. In this case it's inefficient to declare constants in this block because they will be created on each component instantiation, this may be a reason to move them to a separate module, although this can be considered preliminary optimization.

Considering the above, the scope of Vue SFC modules works exactly like it's expected from ESM because this is what they are compiled to.

Vue composition API provides `markRaw` function to additionally prevent constant objects from being made reactive when they are used inside reactive ones like `data`, in case this is unwanted. The same is done for options API with `Object.freeze` in [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59714524/3731501).

TL;DR: the code in the question is ok, it's correct to use the constants like that in this case.